# Searching for text inside nested object (Backbone.js collection as example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, full-text-search, underscore.js

I have a backbone.js collection where I need to do a fulltextsearch on. The tools I have at hand are the following:

Backbone.js, underscore.js, jQuery

For those not familiar with backbone:

A backbones collection is just an object. Inside the collection there is an array with models. Each model has an array with attributes. I have to search each attribute for a string.

The code I am using for this is:

```
query = 'some user input';

query = $.trim(query);
query = query.replace(/ /gi, '|');

var pattern = new RegExp(query, "i");

// this.collection.forEach is the same as _.each
// only it get's the models from the collection
this.collection.forEach(function(model) {
    var check = true;
    _.each(model.attributes, function(attr){
        if(pattern.test(attr) && check){
            // Do something with the matched item
            check = false;
        }
    }, this);
}, this);
```

Maybe one of the tools I am using has a better way of dealing with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone extends a lot of the underscore methods into the `Collection` class so you can get rid of some of that stuff.  Really you probably want to impliment this on the collection itself as a method, then I would probably look at those keys using a good old fashioned `for` loop, especially if I wanted to break out of it.

```
// in Backbone.Collection.extend
search: function( query, callback ){
  var pattern = new RegExp( $.trim( query ).replace( / /gi, '|' ), "i");
  var collection = this;
  collection.each(function(model) {
      for( k in model.attributes ){
        if( model.attributes.hasOwnProperty(k) && pattern.test(model.attributes[k]) ){ 
          callback.call( collection, model, k ); 
          break; // ends the for loop.
        }
      }
  });

}

// later
collection.search('foo', function( model, attr ){
  console.log('found foo in '+model.cid+' attribute '+attr);
});
```

That said, this would only ever return the first match from the collection.  You may prefer an implementation that returns an array of results as [model, attribute] pairs.

```
// in Backbone.Collection.extend
search: function( query, callback ){
  var matches = [];
  var pattern = new RegExp( $.trim( query ).replace( / /gi, '|' ), "i");
  this.each(function(model) {
      for( k in model.attributes ){
        if( model.attributes.hasOwnProperty(k) && pattern.test(model.attributes[k]) ){ 
          matches.push([model, k]);
        }
      }
  });
  callback.call( this, matches );
}

// later
collection.search('foo', function( matches ){
  _.each(matches, function(match){
    console.log('found foo in '+match[0].cid+' attribute '+match[1]);
  });
});
```

Or, if you wanted an array of models which matched but don't care which attribute matched you can use `filter`

```
// in Backbone.Collection.extend
search: function( query, callback ){
  var pattern = new RegExp( $.trim( query ).replace( / /gi, '|' ), "i");
  callback.call( this, this.filter(function( model ){ 
    for( k in model.attributes ){ 
      if( model.attributes.hasOwnProperty(k) && pattern.test(k) ) 
        return true;
    }
  }));
}

// later
collection.search('foo', function( matches ){
  _.each(matches, function(match){
    console.log('found foo in '+match[0].cid+' somewhere');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A normal for..in will do fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner `each` is kludging a short-circuit so you could switch to [`_.any()`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) instead of your [`_.each()`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) and a flag combination; `any` stops iterating as soon as the callback function returns `true` and also delegates to the native `some` method if available.

```
this.collection.each(function(model) {
    _(model.attributes).any(function(attr, key) {
        if(!pattern.test(attr))
            return false;
        // Do something with the matched item...
        return true;
    });
});
```

I also dropped the context `this` arguments since you're not using `this` anywhere, you can put them back if the "Do something" needs them.

You could look into stemming and a reverse index of the collection if a simple regex search isn't good enough.

Comment: +1 for mentioning _.any. Didn't knew this existed, it looks pretty handy. I will also look into stemming, never heard of that either. But a normal regex is just fine for now.